# How to replace internal HDD with SSD in Mac Mini?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, ssd, startup

I'm a complete nube to Mac (bought Mac Mini 10/Apr/15). So far I have cloned OSX from Internal HDD to USB SSD which is to become my Boot Disk. The HDD is solely to hold a recovery partition, and Data i.e. Photos, Docs Music - how do I achieve this?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: Is there a guide or something you are following? What is your desired end state: replacement of internal HDD by internal SSD or keep the HDD where it is but boot from the USB SSD?

Comment: I think the OP is asking if the SSD will fit in the HDD cable. I also have this question

Answer (score 1):

Boot holding the option key and select the SSD to boot. You can also use system preferences to set it as the default boot drive.

Once the machine will restart (or power on from off) and boot to the SSD, use Disk Utility to erase the HDD and enjoy your new Mac.

Comment: Erasing the internal HDD partition containing OS X will probably result in the deletion of the hidden recovery partition. At least when I tested using a flash drive this occurred. –